# How can I create Tabs inside the fragment?

Tags: android, tabs, fragment

I want to create tabs inside the fragment(not a activity). How can I achieve this? Please tell me some thing about it or tutorial will be good idea.

Comment: This thread will be help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20469877/adding-tab-inside-fragment-in-android

Comment: @Zusee Weekin : Hey Thanks. . Will try it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a Tabs into a fragment, let do it in onCreateView() method of framgent, I think everything is nomal

Comment: should have been a comment