# How to implement action bar nested tabs

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-actionbar-tabs

i am developing one application in that i have to implement action bar nested tabs

can any one suggest me how to approach this situation

**required o/p**

[image]

when i use tabhost innertabs compresed
[image]

Problem solved by adding HorizontalScrollView to TabHost

```
 <HorizontalScrollView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            android:scrollbars="none" >

            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#D8D8D8"
                android:showDividers="middle" >
            </TabWidget>
        </HorizontalScrollView>
```

screen shot after adding HorizontalScrollView

[image]

Comment: This SO question could be helpful for your case http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20469877/adding-tab-inside-fragment-in-android

Comment: sure. i will check it, ThanQ

Comment: Hi Angelova, as you said i use tabhost but tabs compresed, you can check my screenshot.

Comment: Problem solved by adding HorizontalScrollView to TabHost

Comment: This seems like overkill. Why not handle this with another design? Such as a new fragment or activity with the tabs. ActionBar + Tabs + Nested Tabs is way too much.

Comment: ok, i will think on it,how to disable action bar tabs scroll...