# Cannot cast v4.FragmentActivity to v4.Fragment in android?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I am using `android.support.v4.app` for `Fragment`, `FragmentTabHost` and `Fragment`. My goal is to show two tabs inside a fragment itself. So I followed the following process:

## ListingFragment

```
public class ListingFragment extends Fragment {
private FragmentTabHost mTabHost;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_listing_home,container, false);
  mTabHost = (FragmentTabHost)rootView.findViewById(R.id.tabHost);

  mTabHost.setup(getActivity(), getChildFragmentManager(), R.id.realtabcontent);
  mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("listfragment").setIndicator("Fragment List"), ListingFragmentTabHost.class, null);
  return rootView;
}
```

## ListingFrgmentTabHost

```
public class ListingFragmentTabHost extends FragmentActivity {
   ....
   ....
}
```

whereas `FragmentActivity` is `import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;`

## fragment_listing_home

```
<android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:id="@+id/tabHost"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/realtabcontent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

</LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost>
```

But when I am running the above snippets. It's throwing me `cast` exception i.e. `java.lang.ClassCastException: com.app.grabhouse.fragment.ListingFragmentTabHost cannot be cast to android.support.v4.app.Fragment`

Why is this happening?

## Edit

After the suggestion I have converted my `FragmentActivity` to `Fragment`

```
public class ListingFragmentTabHost extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_listing_home, container, false);
    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) getView().findViewById(R.id.mRecyclerView);
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    llm.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(llm);

    HomeRecyclerViewAdapter homeRecyclerViewAdapter = new HomeRecyclerViewAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(homeRecyclerViewAdapter);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you need to pass a fragment into `addTab` and `ListingFragmentTabHost` is not a fragment, it is an activity

Comment: That means the first answer of this question is wrong?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20469877/adding-tab-inside-fragment-in-android

Comment: Ah! My bad. Please checkout the above comment

Comment: if you are talking about the one with 52 upvotes no its correct, the difference is he is using nested fragments all being hosted by an activity

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. Now I am using `Fragment` instead of `FragmentActivity` but now it's showing `No tab known for tag null`. I googled and know the cause and defined everything in `OnCreateView` but still it's throwing the same error.

Comment: Please have a look at the Edit-1 section in question itself